# Python PIL set blurring amount when blurring

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Perhaps I'm just missing something major, but I can't find any documentation for setting blur parameters for the blur function with Python PIL.  The official documentation has one example at the top of the page, shown here: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagefilter.htm, for how to blur an image.  But it doesn't say how to specify things such as the kernel type, size of the kernel or anything else.  I'm trying to change the amount of blur applied to the image.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can't set these easily (e.g., in a constructor), but `BLUR.filterargs` is a tuple containing some stuff that looks suspiciously like the height/width of the blur ellipse (first element), a scale (second element), an offset (third element), and a 5x5 convolution kernel (fourth element). You could subclass `BLUR` and set a new `filterargs` on the subclass, or instantiate it and set that attribute on the instance.